# Apache 2.4.4 issue with PHP 5.5.1

Tags: php, apache2, php-5.5

I am having a problem setting up PHP 5.5.1 on Windows 8 Pro under Apache 2.4.4. I have Apache 2.4.4 x86 and I downloaded PHP 5.5.1 x86 VC11 Thread Safe. When I try to load Apache It returns the error:

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 531 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load
C:/php/php5apache2_4.dll into server: The specified module could not be found.
```

I am staring at the file C:\php\php5apache2_4.dll, so I am 100% positive it exists. Now here is the part I don't understand....

When I download PHP 5.4.17 VC9 Thread Safe and unzip, Apache loads and finds the .dll just fine.

Why does PHP 5.4 install perfectly fine, but PHP 5.5 throws the above error. I have tried to install several times and now I am here because I cannot figure it out on my own.

Thanks!

P.S. I originally asked this question on Server Fault, assuming this was a Server Setup related question, but was directed here, even though I've had questions closed over here that were of this nature. Original Server Fault Question: https://serverfault.com/questions/525029/apache-2-4-4-issue-with-php-5-5-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any chance you have a x64 version of Apache and a x86 version on PHP ? Or maybe the other way around ?

Comment: Such a perfect response! Thanks for your help. I indeed had a 32bit version of apache and a 64bit version of php.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's some compatibility issue with that dll file.. try some other version of php